# Unresolved externals in DirectXTK when disabling intrinsics

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, directx, directx-11

I'm using DirectXTK and I'm getting unresolved externals when I enable no intrinsics , by defining the following `#define _XM_NO_INTRINSICS_`

```
unresolved external symbol "public: void __fastcall DirectX::SpriteBatch
```